# Generate random numbers according to a specific distribution

Tags: python, random

How can I generate random numbers say between 0 and 1, according to the distribution 20%, 80% i.e.

```
for i in range(0, 10):
    print random.randint(0, 1)

>>> 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1
```

- 20% 0s
- 80% 1s

Comment: @MartijnPieters, oops

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make use of the fact that booleans are also integers; `True` is 1 and `False` is 0; the following produces `1` 80% of the time, `0` otherwise:

```
int(random.random() < 0.8)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import random
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(int(random.random() < 0.8) for _ in range(1000))
Counter({1: 798, 0: 202})
```

Comment: You don't think this is a duplicate question @MartijnPieters?

Comment: @simonzack: I think the specific problem is better solved this way than the approach for more numbers as used in the duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

One way to handle it:

```
>>>import random
>>>random.choice(2*[0]+8*[1])
```

To elaborate, this will select at random from a list containing 2 zeros and 8 ones.

Comment: This is horribly inefficient.